# Split bootable ISO

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am a user of Windows and I want to use MAC OS X. I have an ISO image of MAC OS X but the size of an ISO image is more than 7 GB which is not writable on single DVD. I don't have dual-layer DVD writer. So tell me any solution to split the image in 2 parts. And after splitting  it can boot also. I mean to say that when first DVD have finished installation, system will ask for second DVD. Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not possible to split a bootable dvd into 2 parts and making it bootable (and usable). use a dual-layer dvd instead.

Comment: OSX comes on a bootable DVD so why do you need to write it?

Comment: @Mark read the first line of the question, the OP wants to use OSx86, I assume

Comment: But even so an OSX disk is bootable

Comment: I know OSX is in bootable format. But I have an ISO image. So I want to write on DVD but it is too large to write on single DVD. I mentioned above

Comment: I am using windows 7 and I want to install OSX also. Please provide any solution. I am very thankful

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the ISO image on a USB Drive. Or you could network boot it.